# Start servlet container (Jersey Jax RS) from command line

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, glassfish, jetty

I'm packaging an open source application as Jar (command line only) and War. I'd like to include a middle ground option, which is to run from command line as a server (for folks who aren't familir with Java, Servlets, Tomcat etc.) Is there a nice way of doing this? Ideally I don't want to write and maintain code, just include some deps, point a main at my War/Resource class and java -jar thejar.jar -port 8080 and have it start a server for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Payara Micro (which is compatible with GlassFish web) you can package your war, specific arguments (i.e. `--port 8080`) and its dependencies within an "Uber Jar". This will let you start your application using `java -jar thejar.jar`.

To do this:

- Download Payara Micro from [payara.fish/downloads](https://www.payara.fish/downloads).
- Run Payara Micro with the command:
  `java -jar payara-micro-4.1.1.162.jar --port 8080 --deploy test-app.war --outputUberJar thejar.jar`
- This will finish and leave you with a small server (~60MB) bundled with your application, which you can start with the command `java -jar thejar.jar`.

For more details, see the blog on [payara.fish](https://blog.payara.fish/creating-uber-jar-with-payara-micro)